# Is the cat trying to communicate by leaving toys in significant places?

Tags: cats, behavior, psychology, anxiety

My boyfriends cat will often bring toys and leave them in places that seem to have meaning.  This morning he found 3 toys in the spot where he sits to put on his work shoes every morning.  What could this mean?  What is his cat trying to tell him?

Comment: My cat (Toby) does this weird thing where at anytime of the day he will meow and the go to our shoe rack and take a random shoe he carries it and the he drops it in random places I searched and ended up with nothing anything that could tell me why my cat does this I have 3 cats and Toby's the only one who does this and its not a toy it's always a shoe specifically! ![enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1GHAh.jpg)

Answer (score 11):

Cats often leave their "prey" or toys as gifts to show their sign of affection and their craft as master hunters.  Leaving them in places where the cat knows you will be is their way of trying to get your attention for a job well done.  My female cat does this often with me too and I will often praise her for her good work (Tell her good job and pet her a lot).

It could also mean they want to play!  I know my cats will drop their toys at my feet when ever they want to play fetch and they will meow until you pick it up and throw it.

Ultimately though, you will find cat toys in your bed and around places you frequent because they want to show off their abilities as master huntsmen and the "prey" or toy is their way of gifting you that.

Answer (score 3):

As given in the sites [Why does my cat carry her toys around?](https://www.yourcat.co.uk/behavioural-problems/why-does-my-cat-carry-a-toy-around-while-miaowing-loudly.html) and [Cat care and cat psychology](https://www.purina.co.uk/cats/behaviour-and-training/understanding-cat-behaviour/cat-care-and-cat-psychology):

Today's domestic cats are descendants of wild cats who started taking the advantage of the abundance of mice around food grain stores in human civilizations 4000 years back. However, many cats today are born indoors and are fed and loved throughout their life as part of a family.

But your cat's brain and emotional system are still designed for the hunt!
So rather than hunting actual rodents, your cat will enjoy chasing and pouncing on a toy mouse.

Now cats carry their prize catch for two reasons.

First is that, when cats catch their prey, they take it back to their core territory to eat. Here you cat's core territory may be according to his imagination.

Second is that they find somewhere to hide it. Typically this means hiding the prey under dry leaves or sandy soil so they become desiccated instead of rotting. When they are hungry and short of fresh prey, they will resort to this temporary store of mummified food. Your cat may also imagine that some places are safe to hide their catch.

So more than communicating with you, I think it is the altered behaviour of domestic cats to suit their natural instinct.